# templated member function and argument forwarding

Tags: c++, templates, perfect-forwarding

I am playing with containers in my c++ playground and I encountered rather technical problem.

I am trying to implement an emplace method for the container. For now it should take an already constructed element and pass it into the allocator construct method.

I ended up with three methods, templated `emplaceA` and a couple `emplaceB1`,`emplaceB2`. All work as intended.

My problem is `emplaceA` doesn't explicitly state that `Arg` can be only `T` (that's what I want). And `emplaceB1`,`emplaceB2` provides almost the same implementation on two different places (I see it as a flaw).

Is there a workaround?

```
template<class T, class A> class container {
public:
    using allocator_traits  = typename std::allocator_traits<A>;
...
    template<class Arg> void emplaceA (int n, Arg&& arg){
        allocator_traits::construct(allocator_, data_+n, std::forward<Arg>(arg));};

    void emplaceB1(int n, const T& t){
        allocator_traits::construct(allocator_, data_+n, t);};

    void emplaceB2(int n, T&& t){
        allocator_traits::construct(allocator_, data_+n, std::move(t));};
...
};
```

Comment: You do know that C++ have function overloading, meaning you can have two (or more) functions with the same name but different arguments?

Comment: This is a very strange emplace implementation

Comment: This looks more like `push_back` than `emplace`. If this would make you feel better about `emplaceB1` and `emplaceB2`, [`std::vector::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) also comes in the same two flavors.

Comment: yeah, I know about function overloading.  Well it is not the complete implementation. It is just a sketch of the problem. An emplace method should probably take the same arguments as constructors and do some workaround when something is already in the desired position...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restrict a templated function, you can use sfinae to prevent unwanted types to be sent.

In the following example, we restrict your template function to be callable only if `Arg` is convertible to `T`. Note that `is_convertible` will work even if the two types are the same.

```
template<class Arg, std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<Arg, T>::value, int> = 0>
void emplaceA(int n, Arg&& arg){
    // ...
}
```

Don't forget to include the header [`<type_traits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits)

---

Of course, if you want to check if the type sent is strictly `T`, you may want to use `std::is_same` with the decayed type.

```
template<class Arg, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::decay_t<Arg>, T>::value, int> = 0>
void emplaceA(int n, Arg&& arg){
    // ...
}
```

Comment: ok,thanks. I don't know this stuff so it is great I have a hint where to look.

Comment: @JiříLechner `<type_traits>` in the answer is a link to a good documentation page.

`