# Forwarding member function arguments

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

Thing simple enough, I want to forward the call of a member function, along with its arguments, as described in the following snippet.

Please note that this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32016749/forwarding-arguments-to-template-member-function), nor [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39453180/templated-member-function-and-argument-forwarding).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<class Function, class ... Args>
auto forward_args(Function&& f, Args&& ... args)
{
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int f(int i) { return i; }

struct A {
  int get(int i) const { return i; }  
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << forward_args(f, 2) << std::endl; //ok
    
    A a;
    //std::cout << forward_args(&A::get, a, 2) << std::endl; //ko
        
    static auto wrong_wrapper = &A::get;
    //std::cout << forward_args(wrong_wrapper, a, 2) << std::endl; //ko again
        
    static std::function<int (const A&, int)> wrapper = &A::get;
    std::cout << forward_args(wrapper, a, 2) << std::endl;
}
```

The commented lines in the `main` function don't compile (g++ 10.2.0 -- `error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘f (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* f) (...)’`)

I don't quite understand what the compiler is trying to tell me, considering the last cll with the `std::function` wrapper does work. And, beside fixing the code, I'd also like to know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Use `return std::invoke(std::forward<Function>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);`

Comment: did you try using pointer to function as your function template argument?

Answer (score 5):

Calling a member function through pointer-to-member still requires `this` pointer, as in usual (direct) invocations. Simply put, you could succeeded calling `A::get()` like

```
static auto wrong_wrapper = &A::get;
(a.*wrong_wrapper)(2);
```

but what you got after `forward_args` was instantiated is

```
A::get(a, 2);
```

which is not the correct syntax in its nature.

**Solution**

As it has been already said in the comments section, if you are allowed to use C++17, employ [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke). If you aren't, you can work it around using [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper), which accepts any callable type.

```
template<class Function, class ... Args>
auto forward_args(Function f, Args&& ... args)
{
    return std::ref(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

I don't forward `f` here because `std::reference_wrapper` requires that the object passed is not an rval.

**UPD:**

Don't forget to specify the trailing return type of `forward_args` if you use C++11

```
template<class Function, class ... Args>
auto forward_args(Function f, Args&& ... args) -> decltype(std::ref(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
    return std::ref(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: Didn't know `reference_wrapper` could do that. That's kind of neat.

Comment: Came across it once reading https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable

Answer (score 1):

`std::function` works because it uses [std::invoke](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) which handles calling pointer to member function.

As the solution you could write:

```
template<class Function, class ... Args>
auto forward_args(Function&& f, Args&& ... args) {
    return std::invoke(std::forward<Function>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

---

Syntax for calling member function for an object are:

```
obj.memberFunction();
obj->memberFunction();
```

or if you have a pointer to member function:

```
using Ptr = int (A::*)(int) const;
Ptr p = &A::get;
A a;
(a.*p)(1);     // [1]
(obj.*memberFuncPtr)(args...);
```

the line [1] is valid syntax for calling member function pointed by a pointer. In your case you try `A::get(a,2)` which is just not valid and cannot work.

Comment: Funnily enough if you don't care about SFINAE you can simplify to `template<class ... Args> auto forward_args(Args&& ... args) { return std::invoke(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }`

Comment: `decltype(auto)` seems more appropriate, especially if `f` can return reference type.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, first thing, I still don't understand why `forward_args(&A::get, a, 2)` doesn't work. Part of the answer was "you need `this`", but I actually provide it with the second parameter, right ? How is that different from the `std::function` wrapper ?

On the other hand, while the workarounds proposed in above answer work on the snippet, I actually simplified my original problem too much. I actually need to launch tasks asynchronously, in the following code

- thread safety has been removed
- yeah, I want to pack all calls in a single data structure, namely `tasks`, which is wy I start building up wrappers
- I don't understand how I can use the proposed solutions to the code below.

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <functional>
#include <queue>

std::queue<std::function<void()>> tasks;

template<class Function, class ... Args>
auto enqueue(Function&& f, Args&& ... args) -> std::future<decltype(f(args...))>
{
    std::function<decltype(f(args...))()> func = std::bind(std::forward<Function>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    auto task_ptr = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<decltype(f(args...))()>>(func);

    std::function<void()> wrapper = [task_ptr]() //wrapper to match types of 'tasks'... ugly
    {
        (*task_ptr)();
    };
        
    tasks.push(wrapper);        

    return task_ptr->get_future();
}

void indep() {}

struct A {
  int get(int i) const { return i; }  
};

int main()
{
    enqueue(indep);
    
    A a;
    //enqueue(&A::get, a, 2); //wrong
    
    static auto wrapper_wrong = &A::get;
    //enqueue(wrapper_wrong, a, 2); //wrong again
    
    static std::function<int(const A&,int)> wrapper = &A::get;
    enqueue(wrapper, a, 2); //ok
    
    static auto autoptr = std::mem_fn(&A::get);
    enqueue(autoptr, a, 2); //ok again
}
```